# How can I display Xaml message as formatted text in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, chat

I am building a chat application and I am receiving xaml string that I would like to display in my RichtextBox(chatBox) as formatted text. This is what I managed to do so far.

How to display received xaml string as formatted text in Richtextbox in chat application?

```
        while (true)
         {

                        recv = ns.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                        msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, recv);

                        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(msg);////interpretacja xaml reader
                        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);//xaml reader
                        Section sec = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader); 
    chatBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => chatBox.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("partner "+time+":\n" + msg )))));
}
```

This is how I send message(displaying sent message as formatted string works well)

```
void buttonlick()
{
 string msg = RTFfromat.GetRTF(messageBox);//konwersja wiadomosc na xaml string

            messageBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();


            ///intepreting xaml message
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(msg);////interpretacja xaml reader
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);//xaml reader
            Section sec = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as Section;/////

            // send msg
            ns.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg), 0, msg.Length);
            ns.Flush();


            //change background color
            sec.SetValue(Paragraph.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.LightSkyBlue);

            //adding formatted text message nto chatbox
            chatBox.Document.Blocks.Add(sec.Blocks.FirstBlock);
}
```

and This is how I manage to convert string text** text to xaml String

```
public static string GetRTF(RichTextBox rt)
        {
            TextRange range = new TextRange(rt.Document.ContentStart, rt.Document.ContentEnd);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            range.Save(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);
            string xamlText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
            return xamlText;
        }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Serialize the `Document` of a RichTextBox like this:

```
var xaml = XamlWriter.Save(richTextBox.Document);
```

Deserialize it like this:

```
richTextBox.Document = XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as FlowDocument;
```